# Why isn't this nested loop working?

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get this to loop through to the next row. The inner two loops are working fine from what i can tell using the debugger but it never goes to the next row. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub PopulateData()
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim locationRow As Integer
Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order_LVL")
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim iRow As Integer

For iRow = 1 To Lastrow
Dim cellj As Range
    For Each cellj In s1.Range("B:F")
    locationRow = 1
    Dim celli As Range
        For Each celli In s2.Range("B1:F1")
        Dim currentrow As Long
        currentrow = iRow + 1
            If s1.Cells(currentrow, cellj.Column).Value = 0 Then

            ElseIf s1.Cells(currentrow, cellj.Column).Value <>   s2.Cells(locationRow, celli.Column).Value And s2.Cells(currentrow, celli.Column).Value = 0 Then
            s2.Cells(currentrow, celli.Column).Value = 0
            Else: s2.Cells(currentrow, celli.Column).Value = 1 'indicates that this order features a line from this location
            End If
        Next celli
    Next cellj
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows are we talking? Is `Integer` enough?

Comment: actually not a lot, this sheet only has 15 rows. I'll try changing it though!

Comment: OK. That should be fine, then. What is in column 1 in Order_LVL?

Comment: column 1 in both sheets are order numbers. In Order_LVL there's "line numbers" as the other column headers and in the corresponding cells i have integers indicating the location of that line within that order. Then in sheet 1 I have the location integers as the other column headers and I want to loop through each order in Order_LVL and look at each cell within that row and compare it to each of the location headers in sheet 1. If a cell in order_LVL matches a location integer header, I want to put a "1" in that corresponding cell in sheet1. The order rows are in the same order on both sheets

Comment: @LaurenNeely Are you trying to loop through the cells in the range? If so Dim `celli` and `cellj` as `cells` then use `for each cellj in s1.Range("B:F").cells` I'm pretty sure you could do this in two loops instead of three as well.

Comment: @LaurenNeely is it putting all zeros in the first row, is that what is happenind? Or can you tell me what happens, if not that?

Comment: @Tom when I change it cells, it gives me an error saying user type not defined. And could i make it just two loops? I'm looping through rows and then cells within that row and comparing those cells to a loop of column headers. But if I can make it two loops that would definitely be preferred.

Comment: @LaurenNeely what happens if you add parentheses? `ElseIf s1.Cells(currentrow, cellj.Column).Value <>   (s2.Cells(locationRow, celli.Column).Value And s2.Cells(currentrow, celli.Column).Value = 0) Then`

Comment: @mattCremeens. It does what I want it to do for the first row. But then after it makes all of the comparisons for the first row, it doesn't move to the next row, it just keeps going through the first row again.

Comment: @LaurenNeely Please have a look at my answer with just two loops. I also noticed that in your code you're setting `lastrow` to find the end of column `A` and not the actual range you're using. Therefore it will only be looping through the number of rows in Column `A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this on some test data (Note I haven't tested it myself but re-written it with only two loops)

```
Sub PopulateData()
Dim s1 As Worksheet: Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As range: Dim rng2 As range
Dim cell: Dim header

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ThisWorkbook
    Set s1 = .Sheets("Order_LVL")
    Set s2 = .Sheets("sheet1")
End With

With s1
    Set rng = range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row, 6)) ' Used Range in Order_LVL
End With

Set rng2 = range(s2.Cells(1, 2), s2.Cells(1, 6)) 'Header range in sheet1

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    For Each header In rng2.Cells
        If cell.value = 0 Then

        ElseIf cell.value <> header.value And s2.Cells(cell.Row, header.Column).value = 0 Then
            s2.Cells(cell.Row, header.Column).value = 0 ' Not sure why you're doing this - if it is already 0 why set it back to 0. Left it in for continuity
        Else
            s2.Cells(cell.Row, header.Column).value = 1 ' indicates that this order features a line from this location
        End If
    Next header
Next cell

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

It should do what you want if I've understood correctly.

Comment: @LaurenNeely no problem - I've also commented above in where I think you had an error. Make sure you are counting the rows in the correct column for future coding :)

Comment: @LaurenNeely Have also just seen I've called the macro 'PopulateDate()' where as you have got it as 'PopulateData()' Please change this in your code just in case you have issues calling it from other macros (if you're doing so)